# People picker not finding specific AD groups

Tags: active-directory, people-picker

We have configured our people picker to look in two domains, the local domain and a Full two-way trusted domain.

It seemed to be working fine, but then we realized that it wasn't finding all of the Groups from the second domain, Some Groups where Missing, some other groups were not.

Also we have to do this only by configuring the people picker as we can't use the User profiler to import users.

Thank you

Comment: Additional Details : 

This is a Farm issue, There's another farm configured in a similar way and their people picker can see all the groups, unfortunately they don't know anymore how was their people picker configured as the developer is no longer there

Comment: Found the reason of the error but still looking if there's a workaround for this 

the difference between the visible and not visible groups is the group scope 

we can see the local groups from the remote domain, but not the local ones, is possible to include the local groups from the trusted domain in the people query